# Having trouble to use [...Array(stateValue)] in React. Not sure if it's the proper way

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have this very simple carousel of posts I made with Next.js/React and Chakra-UI for a blog, that does not use any external lib or component and it seems to work fine until some where I'm trying to apply some responsiveness using Chakra's `useBreakpointValues()` to return different formats on each point.
I'm trying to keep it simple, so I decided to use only Chakra and React for this.

EDIT: as @ggorlen pointed out, this issue was not properly written. So I made this [small reproduction](https://github.com/eduoliveira85/blog-carousel-example) containing just the necessary for the logic of this carouse, hoping it would help to illustrate the problem. There's just the index.js with the carousel and some components all commented. Only next.js and chakra-ui were used.

The content is fed through Sanity API and filtered by categories using context

```
const postsByCategories = posts.filter(el => el.categorias.find(item => item.slug === selected))
```

In this setup, the layout for the carousel changes with display width using useBreakpointValues(), so it will have four posts shown on larger screens, three on smallers, two on tablets and one on mobile.

Here it is how it looks now in my large monitor.
[image]

The logic behind it is simple: the length of postByCategories is divided by how many posts each breakpoint is allowed to display and then rounded up. This will be used to change the state on each category.

```
const breakpointValue = useBreakpointValue({xs: 1, sm: 2, lg: 3, xl: 4}) // this is a chakra-ui/react function
const [maxValue, setMaxValue] = useState(1); // at least one post will be shown, so this state is started like this. It doesn't matter, really
useEffect(() => { // this does the calculation for each category
        setMaxValue(Math.ceil(postsByCategories.length / breakpointValue ));
      })
```

This way I can set up a pair of small functions to change pages using just sums and subtractions for each button.

```
const handleClickUp = () => {
        if (count == maxValue) {
          null
        } else {
          setCount(count + 1)
        }
      }
const handleClickDown = () => {
        if (count == 1) {
          null
        } else {
          setCount(count - 1)
        }
      }
```

Now I can cycle through pages in each breakpoint, using a simple function for `transform` props on `carousel--items` element, which will slide the content within the window of a parent box that hides what's overflown:

```
<Box
  className="carrousel--wrapper"
  w="100%"
  overflow="hidden"
 >
 <Flex
   className="carrousel--items"
   flexDir={[
    'column',
    ,
    "row"
    ]}
    wrap="nowrap"
    transition="all .15s ease-in-out"
    transform={[
     `translateX(calc(-100% * ${count-1}))`
    ]}
    justifyContent="flex-start"
    w={maxValue > 1 ? "fit-content" : '100%'}
   >
     {postsByCategories.map((post, i) => {
       return (
         <PostBox
           flex="0 0 "
           flexBasis={[
            '100%',
            ,
            'calc(50% - .5rem)',
            'calc(33% - .5rem)',
            'calc(25% - .5rem)'
          ]}
          key={i}
          post={post}
          mx={1}
          />
          )
      })}
  </Flex>
</Box>
```

And it works great.

However, I was using a simple trick to generate the navigation dots under the posts, which was an Array of undefined items that would load the number of dots according to page numbers.

```
{[...Array(3)]
  .map((item, i) => {
    return <Dots />
  })}
```

No reason for using three in there. Just looked good to align things. But then the idea was to change it for `maxValue` and have the right number of dots for each category.

However, it seems I can't use this state for retrieve this map function.
[image]

And I've tested maxValue on console. It returns the right one when using `3` as a value for `[...Array()]`

[image]

But NaN for `[...Array(maxValue)]`

[image]

I don't really understand why it doesn't work. My guess is that it have something to do with the way `Array()` but I can't seem to find the issue by myself. Maybe I'm missing something here.

Is there something wrong with this proposition that I should know? Thanks in advance

Comment: The code is a little too broken up into small, non-runnable parts taken out of context to make it possible to assist here. Clearly, `maxValue` is winding up as NaN but I don't see anything obvious from the snippets posted that would cause this to happen. See [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: The `object` keys defined for `breakpointValue` should be `base`, `sm`, `lg` and `xl`. Which means `xs` will be replaced with `base`

Comment: @ggorlen sorry for that. Will try to assemble a minimal repro. tomorrow asap.

Comment: @shadow-lad you're right! My mistake.

Comment: @ggorlen I've edited the post to add a repo I just made containing all that is needed to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out the problem from your small reproduction.

From your overrides, I found the problem. It seems the styles object are breaking the breakpoints you've set on your `extendTheme`.

```
const overrides = extendTheme({
  // breakpoints should be after the styles object
  breakpoints,
  styles: {
    global: {
      html: {
        fontSize: "21px",
        lineHeight: "32px"
      }
    }
  },
});
```

Just move your breakpoints after the styles.

```
const overrides = extendTheme({
  styles: {
    global: {
      html: {
        fontSize: "21px",
        lineHeight: "32px"
      }
    }
  },
  // all good 
  breakpoints,
});
```

I also wanna point out that you had one comment with the `useEffect` under `PanelContent`.

// this will set the n# of pages on mount

If you want the effect to run only on mount, you might want to add an empty dependency list. `useEffect(() => {}, [])`.

EDIT:
Changing the `[...Array(maxValue)]`.

```
const breakpointValue = useBreakpointValue({
    sm: 0,
    md: 1,
    lg: 2,
    xl: 3,
    "2xl": 4
  });
```

I've changed your useEffect to do the following. This should dynamically generate your dots on the `PanelContent`

```
useEffect(() => {
  // this will set the n# of pages on mount
  setMaxValue(
    Math.ceil(
      breakpointValue === 0
        ? 1
        : postsByCategories.length / (breakpointValue + 1)
    )
  );
}, []);
```

[Codesandbox with a fixed `useBreakpointValue`](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-dynamic-dots-fork-xldns)

Comment: First of all, thanks for your feedback. From the codesandbox itself I saw that the problem was still there and I realised that perhaps I wasn't able to make myself clear. The problem is in the way I am using `[...Array(n)].map` to render the dots under the slider. This should be dynamic for each category, so my idea was to use `maxValue` like `[...Array(maxValue)]` so it would generate the right amount of empty objects in that array, just so I have the dots to work with. I've corrected what you pointed out tho. Thanks for these lessons. Didn't know that there's a matter of order in extendTheme

Comment: Let me edit my codesandbox. I've already found what you want. So you want those dots to be dynamically generated based on what fits on the page, right?

Comment: I've edited my answer & the codesandbox to handle your problem with the rendering of the dots too.

Comment: You nailed it. I'm reading the codesandbox you edited and applied it to the real project. Worked like a charm. I wasn't really getting what's was wrong but now I get it. Thank you for your feedback and support on this